# I cannot find the library libXp.so.6 for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

How can I install the library libXp.so.6 on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: LibXp is deprecated, you probably should not install it. It is also not maintained. The last commit was 5-6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from Debian [Jessie repository](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXp.so.6) and install by terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Jessie repository is no longer available.